# C# printing for loop

Tags: c#

I want to print this:-

         `1
        121
       12321
      1234321
     123454321`

This program prints this. What could be the error in the program  ? In the for loop ? Please tell me how to fix this. What is the error in the logic I am using. If so, what is the problem in my logic ? How should I think for algorithms in the near future ? :-

     `1
    12
   123
  123432
 123454321`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a, b, c, d, e;
            b = 6;
            for(a=b;a>=1;a--)
            {
                for (c = a; c >=1; c--)
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                for(d=1; d<=b-a;d++)
                {
                    Console.Write(d);
                }
                for (e = b-a-1; e>=a; e--)
                {
                    Console.Write(e);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me the problem in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is in the line `for (e = b-a-1; e>=a; e--)`

change it to simply `for (e = b-a-1; e>=1; e--)`

Answer (score 3):

class Program

{

static void Main(string[] args)

```
    {
        int a = 1, b, s = 1, n = 5;
        for (; a <= n; s = s * 10 + 1)
        {
            for (b = n - a; b >= 1; b--)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            Console.Write(s * s);
            Console.WriteLine();
            a++;
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you explain this please ! It works properly but I didnt understand !

Comment: Rahul, you can do a dry run for it and note that n is no. of lines in pattern its 5

Answer (score 1):

@chouaib is absolutely correct about where the problem lies in your code.

However we need to work on your code and how it is written.

The first thing is your variable names. `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e` mean nothing. From looking at and reading this code i can not work out what it will do. You want your code to be easily understood by someone reading it.
Use variable names that have meaning. For a problem like this I might use `row` and `column`, depending on my approach to solve it.

Which brings me to the next thing to think about, how to go about solving this problem.
You effectively have a table that you are writing values to with rows and columns. So a good place to start would be to iterate over the columns of each row. Something like

```
int totalNumberOfRows = 5;
int totalNumberOfColumns = 9;
// Iterate over each row
for (int row = 0; row < totalNumberOfRows; row++)
{
    // Iterate over each column of each row
    for (int column = 0; column < totalNumberOfColumns; column++)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Next, simplify the problem a bit. Let's ignore the whitespace making it into a nice pyramid. Just try and print

```
1
121
12321
etc...
```

Once you've achieved that then you're nearly there.
If you look at a problem and you can't work out how to solve it, try to break it down into smaller, easier problems.

When you write code think about making it easy for someone else to read and understand. Code needs to be maintainable and extensible, which means that when someone needs to work on the code to add to it, or fix a bug, they don't want to have to spend hours just reading it to understand it.